# yii2: How to login using two tables of database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2-basic-app

I have two tables in database table1 and table2 and i am trying to login using table1 and table2 username and password.I have separate models for table1 and table2. 
My LoginForm is

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{

public $email;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;
public $status;
private $_user = false; 
/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */

 public function validatePassword($attribute)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $pass= (table1::find()->where(['Password'=>$this->password] ) OR (table2::find()->where(['Password'=>$this->password] ) ->one()));
        if (!$user || !$pass) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect email or password.');
        }
    }
    }
/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */

public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->status, $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */

public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
    $this->_user =Table1::findByEmail_id([$this->email ]) OR Table2::findByEmail_id([$this->email ]);
    }
    return $this->_user ;   
}
```

}

I tried like this but i can't login,i got error

PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Call to a member function validatePassword() on a non-object

Can anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy this function in Table1 and Table2

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}
```

You can also refer the below link:
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii-2-user-login-from-database/

Comment: password_hash is used for password verification. If you do not have password hash, you can modify the function as per your requirement. IN your code, validatePassword is using $user->validatePassword($this->password) and it is throwing error because it is not present in the model.

Comment: i want to validate two tables password so i changed validatePassword function..... I edited my question.